# CocoaPods podspec lint failure - file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcodebuild, cocoapods

I'm trying to distribute my pod, but I'm having issues with it's validation.

When I'm trying to lint against my .podspec I'm getting:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  path/to/my/source/file.m:14:9: fatal error: 'KeyValueObjectMapping/DCKeyValueObjectMapping.h' file not found
```

I tried to preserve the path to their framework with different variations like

```
 s.preserve_paths = 'KeyValueObjectMapping.framework/*'
```

or

```
 s.preserve_paths = '${PODS_ROOT}/Vendor/KeyValueObjectMapping/KeyValueObjectMapping.framework'
```

& other variations but that way I'm getting one more error:

```
    - ERROR | [iOS] The `preserve_paths` pattern did not match any file.
```

I also tried different other things which I saw on other issues like:

```
  s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Vendor/KeyValueObjectMapping/KeyValueObjectMapping.framework"','FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/Vendor/KeyValueObjectMapping/*"' }
  s.framework = 'KeyValueObjectMapping'
```

The project builds fine with Xcode5 & with xcodebuild with it's default setup, I'm getting this issue only when validating it for Cocoapods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into this issue trying to create a custom Podspec and add the [RevMob](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html) and [Heyzap](http://developers.heyzap.com/) SDKs as dependencies.

I kept getting the following error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  MyProject/MyProjectSubDir/AnotherDir/CustomAd.h:10:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  MyProject/MyProjectSubDir/AnotherDir/FacebookController.m:18:9: fatal error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found
```

Then when I specified the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS for RevMob, I would get the same error but for Heyzap's SDK.

The solution for me was to create a subspec and specify search paths for each of the SDKs giving me issues. Here:

```
s.subspec "Heyzap" do |ss|
    ss.dependency "Heyzap", "~> 6.4.4"
    ss.xcconfig = { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(PODS_ROOT)/Heyzap"}
end

s.subspec "RevMob" do |ss|
    ss.dependency "RevMob", "~> 7.4.8"
    ss.xcconfig = { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(PODS_ROOT)/RevMob"}
end
```

My `pod spec lint` now runs & builds without error.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with .h (from external libs) included in my own headers, as i am building a static library for our projects. Your solution worked for me !